# How to draw coordinates in JavaScript Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing, visualization, polynomials

I want to draw polynomials like 4x^2+3x+4 with JavaScript and Canvas. For this I wrote a function in JavaScript that calculates these values of this polynomials and return 2000 x/y coordinates in Interval [-20, +20]. How i can draw this coordinates in Canvas?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following code may help you. Within it, a canvas is created, the width and height is set to 40 (to simulate -20 to 20), then the points, placed in an array, are combined into [Path2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D) [path data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths). 20 is added to the x coordinates, because a canvas displays only coordinates on the positive plane, and the y coordinates are made negative and 40 is added to them because [0, 0] on a canvas is the top left, and positive y coordinates go down instead of up.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
 var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 canvas.width = 40;
 canvas.height = 40;
 var points = [];
 for(var i = -20; i <= 20; i+= 0.01) {
  points.push(i+20, -(4*i**2+3*i+4)+40);
 }
 var path = new Path2D('M '+points.shift()+' '+points.shift()+' L '+points.join(' '));
 context.stroke(path);
 document.body.append(canvas);
});
```

I would recommend, however, using an SVG instead -- if possible. It's a very similar idea, but it may produce a higher quality result. In this example, an svg element and a path element are created, the SVG's viewBox is set to -20 to 20 on both axis, then the same path data in the previous example is added to the path's 'd' attribute. X and Y aren't changed as much because the SVG's viewBox was changed, but Y is still made negative -- for the same reason as the canvas solution.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
 var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
 var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
 var points = [];
 for(var i = -20; i <= 20; i+= 0.01) {
  points.push(i, -(4*i**2+3*i+4));
 }
 svg.setAttribute('viewBox', '-20 -20 40 40');
 path.setAttribute('d', 'M '+points.shift()+' '+points.shift()+' L '+points.join(' '));
 path.setAttribute('fill', 'transparent');
 path.setAttribute('stroke', 'black');
 svg.append(path);
 document.body.append(svg);
});
```

You might have stored your coordinates in an array like the following: [[x, y], [x, y]]. If so, this solution will work if [array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) is used to convert the array to [x, y, x, y].

I may not have properly explained these code snippets, but hopefully this answer is useful to you.